# How to vertically align text to the right of some text using css?

Tags: css

How do I get the text on the right side of the read line to vertically align with the top line?

See image, how to get the text to the right of the red line to line up below with the top text?

[image: http://carzibit.com/carzibit.com/main/assets/Paragraph-Align.png]

Comment: Please provide some code or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Put that text in a div?  Can we see some code?

Comment: code please, or a jsfiddle would help.

Comment: divs with inline-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you got something like this:

```
<div class="note">
    <span class="label">Note:</span>
    <span class="text">Certification and E-Tests are...</span>
</div>
```

I'd use the `HTML` tags `dl`, `dt` & `dd` ([Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dd.asp)) for it:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Note:</dt>
    <dd>Certificaiton and E-Test are not required for entry to Carbuitlz but seller must agree to an on-site mechanic inspection at seller's price</dd>
</dl>
```

Applying almost no `CSS`:

```
dl dt { float:left; }
```

---

### The [result](http://jsfiddle.net/RienNeVaPlus/J3Gak/):

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding element of CSS.

HTML

```
<div class=format>Certificaiton and E-Test are not required for entry to Carbuitlz but seller must agree to an on-site mechanic inspection at seller's price</div>
```

CSS

```
    .format{
    padding-left:100px;
}
```

here is JSFiddle Link

http://jsfiddle.net/ashishtyagi10/GmqLP/