# Aligning images with variable length text

Tags: html, css

What would be the best way to accomplish something like this, but where the icons are vertically-aligned with the middle of the text (which has variable length)?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/OcGLUoG.png]

The icons are CSS sprites, with the background moving over 26px when hovering on the icon or associated text

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904866/how-to-vertically-align-text-to-the-right-of-some-text-using-css/16905130#16905130)

Comment: The top of the image should be aligned to the top of the text?  Or the center of the image should be aligned to the center of the entire block of text?

Comment: Sorry, image should be aligned - middle of image to middle of text block. Should have made that clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### New answer compatible with CSS sprites

In response to @Octavian's feedback, here's a different way of dealing with the issue that still allows the use of CSS sprites.  The solution here is to use `display:table` on the `li` and `display:table-cell` on its children, in order to vertical align them.  Then, instead of an image, a placeholder `div` with a `background-image` can be used for the sprites.  Here's a jsFiddle, and the code is below:

**CSS**

```
ul {padding-left:0;}

li {display:table;margin-bottom:20px;}

.image-holder {
    display:table-cell;
    width:26px;
    height:26px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-image:url('http://placehold.it/52x26');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left center;
}

li:hover .image-holder {background-position:right center;}

.text {padding-left:30px;display:table-cell;}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="image-holder"></div>
        <span class="text" style="display:table-cell;">www.website.com</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="image-holder"></div>
        <span class="text" style="display:table-cell;">742 Evergreen Terrace<br/>Springfield, SP 12345<br/>United States</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="image-holder"></div>
        <span class="text" style="display:table-cell;">T) (800) 555-5555<br/>F) (800) 666-6666</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### Old answer, more elegant but incompatible with sprites

Another option would be to use each image as a `background-image` positioned in the top middle of each `li`.  The key piece of CSS here is `background-position`, the first argument of which represents the horizontal alignment (`top` in this case) and the second argument of which indicates vertical alignment (`center` in this case).  [Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position).  Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nfggV/6/), and the code is below:

**CSS**

```
li {
    background-position:left center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-left:40px;
    padding:5px 0 5px 60px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    list-style-type:none;
    background-image:url('http://placehold.it/30x30');
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li id="website">www.website.com</li>
    <li id="address">742 Evergreen Terrace<br/>Springfield, SP 12345</li>
    <li id="phone">T) (800) 555-5555<br/>F) (800) 666-6666</li>
    <li id="email">info@website.com</li>
    <li id="share">Share via email</li>
</ul>
```

---

**Edit 1** In response to @cimmanon's comment (thanks!) example now works with images larger than text, and I've posted an accompanying demo.

**Edit 2** Altered in line with @Octavian's comment indicating a need for middle-aligning rather than top-aligning.

**Edit 3** New answer compatible with CSS sprites

Comment: You forgot a demo:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/fvz70zxb.  This only works if the text is taller than the image.

Comment: Thanks guys - this is closer than I managed, but not quite there yet. The center of the image should align with the center of the text. The text will come from a database, and there could be 1 to 4 or more phone numbers, email addresses, etc, so I need the icon to align with the center regardless of the length of the <li>. I can't just adjust the padding for each one.

Comment: @Octavian, sorry; I thought for some reason you wanted top alignment.  I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Another issue here - how do CSS sprites work with li background? When using my sprite as the background, the whole thing shows. Background-size stretches instead of cropping, but since it is a part of the li, I can't just change the width of the container.

Comment: ASGM - Thanks, that works well! I tried changing top left to top center before and it didn't work. Copied and pasted what you have and it is centered! Did something else chance I didn't see?

Comment: @Octavian I don't think my solution will be compatible with sprites, since both rely on `background-position`.  But I'll see if I can find a way around that, or to align in a different way.

Comment: @Octavian, I think I've found an answer compatible with CSS sprites.  Hope it helps.

Comment: @ASGM, BEAUTIFUL! You are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the `line-height` to the height of the image (or 50% for double lines)

Comment: The issue with this is that the number of lines is variable, even within one category. In some instances, for example, the address may be two lines, sometimes it may be 3 or even 4.